# UIView fill height only and crop width

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am trying to do something that I thought would be very easy with `UIView`. However, I'm stuck for few days now. I think I am missing something stupid.

I have an image (let's say 640x480) and I want to display this image in a 60x60 `UIView` in a tableView cell. I want to shrink the content just enough to fit the smaller dimension within the view. The larger dimension (in this case, the length) will be cropped. The new image should be something like 80x60 but only 60x60 should be visible :
(Please see here as I still can not pos images -> http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/9017/23032945.jpg)

I tried `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` and `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` but none of them are giving the result I need :
(Please see here -> http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/7673/90427118.jpg)

`UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` transform my 640x480 image in a 60x60 image and `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` transform it in a 60x45 image

I don't need to animate or pinch or slide or anything, just show the image.

As I am pretty new with iOS, a little help will be more than welcome.

Comment: I found interesting code here : http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/. I'am trying to do exactly what is described with the last image. However I still did not succeed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`? That will have the behaviour your describe if the image view has a shorter/wider aspect than your image.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried this, however it is not what I am looking for. Tis way it is the UIView that is transformed from my 60x60 square into a 80x60 rectangle. I want the image to be transformed and the UIView to remain 60x60.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're saying the "aspect fill" constant I mentioned didn't maintain the aspect ratio of the original image? What kind of UIView are you using? If you have a 60x60 UIImageView with the content mode I suggested, it should work.

Comment: Try setting `clipsToBounds` to YES on your UIImageView.

Comment: You're welcome. If it was helpful, it's polite to accept the answer  by clicking the checkmark next to it.